# Is it safe to delete $OF folder in Windows 10 Home? It has taken up 100 GB

Tags: windows, history

Is it safe to delete `$OF` folder?

[image: windows\Data$OF]

Comment: I would suggest to adjust File history settings to store only last 3-5 copies. This will significantly decrease the used space.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on you; $OF folder is created by File History, File History creates a backup copy of a file/folder whenever it is deleted/modified, and the backup is stored in that $OF folder, the folder grows bigger as you make changes to the filesystem, the backups are made just in case you want the files/folders back, it is only useful when you want to rewind something; If you want to delete it, go ahead and delete it, it will not harm anything, you will free up 100 GB space, the only downside: you can't get previous versions and undelete things without undeleters, but this kind of features are not used everyday, they are only useful when you really need it; I personally don't use File History, because it will fill up precious storage space, but I also can't revert things when I really need to, it's like a double-edged sword; I am sorry but there is no absolute right answer for your question, it really is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

The $OF folder contains files that are created by File History BUT whith a path length greater than 256 characters. 'OF' stands for 'OverFlow'.

@Ξένη Γήινος
I don't think that File History creates a backup of a file when it is deleted. Those versions of the file will be deleted that don't meet the criterion for keeping.